# Get selected text, replace it, etc. using jQuery for a simple editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a small HTML editor using jQuery. I have created my own button-icons for:

- bold
- italics
- underline
- insert hyperlink
- insert image
- unordered list
- ordered list

But I donot know how to get it working. My idea:

- bold: when user clicks on this button, selected text in the editor box() should be replaced with `<b> ..selected_text.. </b>`. Otherwise, insert `<b></b>` at cursor position.
- italic: when user clicks on this button, selected text in the editor box() should be replaced with `<i> ..selected_text.. </i>`. Otherwise, insert `<i></i>` at cursor position.
- same as above for **Underline**
- etc....

So my question is, how to get the selected text from TEXTAREA and how to replace it with the tags? And also, how to insert a text at cursor position (ie. at that blinking line) ?

This is same as the buttons present in Stackoverflow's editor, when you post some questions. (for example, try clicking on the BOLD button in Stackoverflow's editor, when you have selected a text and when not selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **strongly** recommend using a JavaScript library which smooths out the cross-browser differences when working with ranges and selections: [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).

> A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library. It provides a simple standards-based API for performing common DOM Range and Selection tasks in all major browsers, abstracting away the wildly different implementations of this functionality between Internet Explorer and DOM-compliant browsers.
>
> For manipulating selections in `<textarea>` and `<input type="text">` elements, see see Rangy's poorly-named and svelter twin project, [Rangyinputs](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/).

---

> How to get the selected text from TEXTAREA and how to replace it with the tags?

Check out [the Rangy CSS Class Applier Module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) (and [associated demo page](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html)).

Comment: i have a question related to this: what is the proper way(cross-browser compatible) to call a javascript function inside `onMouseDown` event ? Is this `onMouseDown = "myFunction();"` correct way ? It does works though, I want to know the correct way because I am trying to learn now.